# Very confused by this code snippet in C++ (colons and other syntax)

Tags: c++

Specifically line 3. I can't make the question any more precise as I don't even know what the terminology for the syntax is, I have never seen anything like it before. The following code snippet is from an online learning resource I'm following:

```
struct cell { 
    int r,c; 
    cell(int r, int c) : r(r), c(c) {} 
};
```

I know that the colon indicates that you are specifying the amount of bits but following that appears to be a function? But what is the comma for? And why is this all outside the {} brackets.

Comment: Look up `member initializer list`.

Comment: That's a constructor, not a bitfield.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter Ah..I just googled what a semicolon meant in C++ and found that it mean a bitfield

Comment: A colon -- `:`, not a semicolon which is `;`-- in C++ can mean a number of things. In this case, it's being used for a member initializer. It can also be used for bitfields or inheritance. A double colon is used for namespaces.